# Regular expression *y *m *d

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write regular expression for string in format: "(number_of_years)y (number_of_months)m (number_of days)d". Each part of string is optional and should be separated by one space. My variant:

```
/([0-9]+y\s)?([0-9]+m\s)?([0-9]+d)?/
```

is not good because it requires to add space in case of entering only the first or the second part of string.
Examples of good strings:

```
"125y"; "36m"; "8d"; "125y 8d"; "125y 36m"; "36m 8d"; "125y 36m 8d".
```

It should not be allowed to enter space in the end of strings: `*y; *m; *y *m`.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of strings that you would want to match vs strings you would not want to match? I.e., "25y 10m 29d" = good? "25y 10m 35d" = bad? Does every part need to be marked with a 'y/m/d'?

Comment: @RobertTaussig, I have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative version. Space required between items, Order not required

```
^(?:(?:\b\ \b|^)?(?:(\d+y)|(\d+m)|(\d+d)))+
```

Or with Order required

```
^(\d+y)?(?:(\b\ \b|^)(\d+m))?(?:(?:\b\ \b|^)(\d+d))?$
```

Each item in it's own capture group

Comment: The last variant matches all my tests. Thanks a lot! But this regular expression doesn't work in javascript. I couldn't cope with converting it into javascript. Could you kindly help me with this?

Comment: @MyName Sorry, fixed it for Javascript. (forgot Javascript doesn't support conditionals.) Basicly replaced if group matched with if preceded by boundary surrounded space or newline

Answer (score 1):

One can use:

```
^(?!.*\s$)(\d+y\s)?(\d+m\s)?(\d+d)?$
```

[live demo](https://regex101.com/r/74RQSp/5)

Comment: It allows to enter space in the end of strings: `*y; *m; *y *m`

Comment: Thomas, I have found that `78y7m3d` is also valid but it is wrong.

Comment: @Natasha: Remove the `?` after the `\s`

Comment: @Toto, I got that the only valid case is `"125y 36m 8d"`.

Comment: @Natasha what? Show us your implementation

Comment: @ThomasAyoub, only cases `"125y"; "36m"` are not valid. My previous comment is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([0-9]+y\s?)?(((1[0-2])|([1-9]))m\s?)?((([12]?[0-9])|(3[01]))d)?$
```

I'm sure there are a million ways to improve this, but this enforces that there are no more than 12 months or 31 days.

[Examples](https://regex101.com/r/oUkf3v/1)

Comment: Why are you limiting number of days and months? That's not requested by OP.

Comment: Because it seems silly to validate for '1y 13m', etc. To me, it is analogous to accepting '$2.104' instead of '$3.04'. EDIT: I just noticed OP's examples of valid dates. I could swear that '36m' wasn't there initially, but I might be wrong. I thought I was merely making an assumption, but it looks like OP was explicit in what was allowed.